# How to call Class method in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, retrofit2, rx-java2

I know this question has been asked before many times, I have checked the previous questions and none of them suit my needs. I am new to `JSP` but an old-time Java developer. 
I `googled` about different ways to make network calls from a `JSP file` and multiple came but because JSP is a descendant of `Java` I wanted to take this advantage and make something completely different, I Have used `Retrofit` for network calls with `rxJava`.

I made an interface class

```
public interface APIService {
  @GET("getprofiles")
  Single<List<UserProfileRole>> getProfileRoles();
}
```

A `Retrofit` initializer class

```
public class RetrofitService {

  public static Retrofit getRetrofit() {

    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .build();

    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.API)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build();
   }
}
```

And finally `NetworkCallManager` class

```
public class NetworkCallManager {

  public static Single<List<UserProfileRole>> getAllUserProfiles(){
    List<UserProfileRole> mUserProfileRoles = new ArrayList<>();
    APIService service = RetrofitService.getRetrofit().create(APIService.class);
    return service.getProfileRoles();
  }
}
```

My idea is to call the `NetworkCallManager.getAllUserProfiles()` method which returns a `Single` so in my `JSP` I do something like

```
<%@ page import="manager.NetworkCallManager" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ page import="models.UserProfileRole" %>
<%@ page import="io.reactivex.SingleObserver" %>
<%@ page import="io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable" %><%--
Document   : newuserprofiletype
Created on : May 6, 2019, 4:12:01 PM
Author     : aubry
--%>

 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%!

NetworkCallManager.getAllUserProfiles()
    .subscribe(new SingleObserver<List<UserProfileRole>>() {

      @Override
      public void onSubscribe(Disposable disposable) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onSuccess(List<UserProfileRole> userProfileRoles) {
        //Set result to page
      }

      @Override
      public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
      }
    });

%>
```

My only problem is when I call `NetworkCallManager.getAllUserProfiles()` `intelliJ` gives me a `Cannot resolve symbol getAllUserProfiles` but when typing `ManagerCallManager.` `intelliJ` even autocompletes for me.
How do I resolve the function?

Answer (score 0):

Well the solution is heartbreaking, so it turns out I was using the wrong tags

<%!
My code here
%>
`

Instead of the

`<%
My code here
%>`

And now my code works.